antr4 runtime does not exist intellij idea
how to fix these problem:
D:\antlr\test1\src\Main.java:4
java: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
    import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
    import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.printf("Hello and welcome!\n");
    
        }
    }

enter image description here
i am rookie in java i did not much try i cant figure out the problem

This had nothing to do with ANTLR or the IntelliJ plugin. The issue is that the Java compiler cannot find certain classes (in your case they happen to be ANTLR classes). Before using a full blown IDE, it is wise to understand how to compile (and run) classes from your terminal. Try that and make sure you follow a tutorial that explains how to add dependent classes to the CLASSPATH when compiling (and running) Java classes. Good luck.
